# method of variations of parameters in differential equation!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that we have the following second order linear non-homogeneous differential equation with varying coefficients.$(a_0(x),a_1(x),a_2(x), F(x))$

$$a_{0}(x)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+a_{1}(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+a_2(x)y=F(x)$$

Further consider the following second order homogeneous differential equation!

$$a_{0}(x)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+a_{1}(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+a_2(x)y=0$$

The complementary solution to the differential equation is given as

$$y_c=c_1y_1+c_2y_2$$

We assume that $y_1$ and $y_2$ both are linearly independent solution to the corresponding homogeneous differential equation!

By method of variation of parameters we can obtain the particular solution to the above homogeneous differential equation!

$$y_p=v_1(x)y_1+v_2(x)y_2$$

Differentiating with respect to x we have

$$y'_p=v'_1(x)y_1+v'_2(x)y_2+v_1(x)y'_1+v_2(x)y'_2$$

Imposing the second condition for variation of parameters

$$v'_1(x)y_1+v'_2(x)y_2=0$$

So the derivative reduces to

$$y'_p=v_1(x)y'_1+v_2(x)y'_2$$

Again by differentiation!

$$y''_p=v'_1(x)y'_1+v'_2(x)y'_2+v_1(x)y''_1+v_2(x)y''_2$$

Putting them into the differential form!

$$a_0(x)(v'_1(x)y'_1+v'_2(x)y'_2+v_1(x)y''_1+v_2(x)y''_2)+a_1(x)(v_1(x)y'_1+v_2(x)y'_2)+a_2(x)(v_1(x)y_1+v_2(x)y_2)=F(x)$$

In a better form

$$a_0(x)(v_1(x)y''_1)+a_1(x)(v_1(x)y'_1)+a_2(x)(v_1(x)y)+a_0(x)(v_2(x)y''_2)+a_1(x)(v_2(x)y'_2)+a_2(x)(v_2(x)y)+a_0(x)(v'_1(x)y'_1+v'_2(x)y'_2)=F(x)$$

Notice that

$$a_0(x)(v_1(x)y''_1)+a_1(x)(v_1(x)y'_1)+a_2(x)(v_1(x)y)=0$$

$$a_0(x)(v_2(x)y''_2)+a_1(x)(v_2(x)y'_2)+a_2(x)(v_2(x)y)=0$$

Final form is

$$a_0(x)(v'_1(x)y'_1+v'_2(x)y'_2)=F(x)$$
$$(v'_1(x)y'_1+v'_2(x)y'_2)=\frac{F(x)}{a_0(x)}$$

So, the criteria the we mention comes into play
$$v'_1(x)y_1+v'_2(x)y_2=0$$
$$(v'_1(x)y'_1+v'_2(x)y'_2)=\frac{F(x)}{a_0(x)}$$

The above system of linear equation has unique solution since the number of unknowns are the same as the number of equations!

$$v'_1(x)=\frac{\begin{bmatrix}0 & y_2 \\\frac{F(x)}{a_0(x)} & y'_2 \end{bmatrix}}{\begin{bmatrix}y_1 & y_2 \\y_1' & y'_2 \end{bmatrix}}=-\frac{F(x)y_2(x)}{a_0(x)W[y_1,y_2]}$$

$$v'_2(x)=\frac{\begin{bmatrix}y_1 & 0 \\y_1' & \frac{F(x)}{a_0(x)} \end{bmatrix}}{\begin{bmatrix}y_1 & y_2 \\y_1' & y'_2 \end{bmatrix}}=\frac{F(x)y_1(x)}{a_0(x)W[y_1,y_2]}$$

My question is

1)How did the matrix form?

2) Why is the imposed criteria so important?

3) In what cases the method of variation of parameter is invalid

4) Is the variation of parameter related to undetermined coefficients? Is UC a special case of method of variation of parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There are no matrices, only determinants (Cramer's rule for solving systems of equations)
2. The criterion $v'_1(x)y_1+v'_2(x)y_2=0$ is imposed. It simplifies the resulting equations
3. The formulae for $v'_1(x)$ and $v'_2(x)$ breakdown if $a_0(x)=0$ or $W=0$. In the first case you don't have a 2nd order equation anyway so wouldn't be applying this method. The second case doesn't happen because of linear independence. The resulting integrals may be hard to do though.
4. UC is organised guesswork, it's not a special case.